# Issues on 12.04.3 on Asus Notebook with geforce 710m

Tags: wireless, nvidia, asus, nvidia-optimus, nouveau

I have 12.04.3 installed on an ASUS x552CL notebook which has GeForce 710M(optimus).

I have 2 issues:

1. Wireless gets disabled from hardware switch, I resolved it using

   ```
    echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
   ```
2. Nouveau unknow fermi chipset, I solved by installing bumblebee

My questions are:

1. Are those 2 issues which I described above solved in some updates or patches for 12.04.3?

   Because I'm having my 12.04.3 up-to-date didn't solve them.
2. Can i get rid of Nouveau driver ?

   I heard it's buggy. I've read a post of some guy on a forum that removed nouveau and installed the intel integrated video chipset drivers and after that he installed the nvidia drivers and bumblebee.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any update in 12.04.3 or, for that matter, any later Ubuntu version, that addresses the asus_nb_wmi issue. That's why driver parameters exist; if the built-in driver doesn't exactly fit your particular laptop model, you may have success trying a parameter, in your case, wapf=1. Once you have discovered and implemented it, I see nothing wrong with just using it for what it was intended without expecting an immediate update.

Comment: What does wapf stand for ?

Comment: Please see: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/platform/x86/asus-nb-wmi.c and check about lines 44-50.

Comment: thanks, i looked into it, probably going to do something about it